# Array formula to reduce importxml request for large data

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm using formula =index(importxml("https://niftyinvest.com/max-pain/"&A2&"?expiry="&B1,"//h6[@class='center-align padding-10 black darken-2 white-text']"),1,2) where for Col'A' I have nearly 200 values(i.e. name of stocks) and for Col'B' I have fixed value(i.e a fixed date in last week of month let's say 30June2022. Now I want arrayformula so that total no.of reqests per page is reduced. Is it possible anyhow so that there be faster data retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no.  it is not possible to use IMPORTXML in arrayformula.